# How to recognize font types in .png

Tags: font-identification, png

There is a **.psd**
[layout](http://xoo.me/template/details/2609-simplistic-wordpress-blog-theme) & it has different text types in **.png**. How to recognize which font types used in it?
[myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com) does not help.
Any help is appreciated!
Add photo with fonts, what are they?
[image]

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have a collection of font identification resources for you to try. If you can separate out the text with a background as neurtra as possible, that would help you a lot. Should all this fail, you could post an image here, and maybe get some help. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Comment: @Benteh, thanks a lot! But unfortunately these sources didn't help me, so I added a photo with unknown fonts and underline them.

Comment: You can ask the designer who supplied you this, to send an editable file..

Comment: To save a bit of time: "Lucid Theme" is **American Typewriter;** "Tags"/"Categories" is **Helvetica.** The other highlighted text is probably **Open Sans.** When posting images of typefaces for identification, make them as large as possible so that the little things which help can actually be seen.

Comment: @Jack This layout was taken from site and sent to me by the customer, so I'm not familiar with its creator.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks a lot, you really save my time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a screenshot or export an image of a word and upload it to whatthefont.com - This should help you choose a font that closely matches your image. There's still a chance however that you wont have the font on your computer.

**See screenshot below**

[image: Screenshot of MyFonts.com showing matching fonts.]

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this option, but has not achieved the desired result.

Comment: @kirbrown Here is the link of the title text found on myfonts.com ('what the font' section) as seen here:  [http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=L&ch%5B1%5D=&ch%5B2%5D=U&ch%5B3%5D=C&ch%5B4%5D=I&ch%5B5%5D=D&ch%5B6%5D=T&ch%5B7%5D=H&ch%5B8%5D=E&ch%5B9%5D=M&ch%5B10%5D=E&wtfserver=wtf_e_41&id=0025e501535186d5000a40200000712c&glyphcount=11&imageid=0&x=40&y=37] The best choice is to get the original photoshop file if you can.

Comment: Error
Your search session has expired. Please start again. [jobmanager.cc:100]  - Whats a pity, anyway - thanks for watching!

Comment: See edited reply. As @AndrewLeach commentated above with all the correct fonts - this post was just letting you know a tool to help you find fonts in the future.

Comment: Finally it worked, thanks, but not with all fonts, which I tried.